# Advanced DNS settings for BIND regarding a sub domain for my local home network that integrates nicely into its parent domain (on an external network)

Tags: dns

The intent of this post is that I ran into things I had a hard time understanding and wish to implement things in a more professional and objectively better way. Some of my choices I simply don't know to be good or bad. I believe the open questions are very instructive for people that can follow documentation to set up a working local DNS server - but wish to understand and learn how things are done the right way. Hence I opted to ask here!

I have a domain `sakujo.tld` and use namecheap's FreeDNS service as the authorized DNS. I configured entries for the following host.domains in their zone configuration

- `nas.home.sakujo.tld`, `gateway.home.sakujo.tld` (A record via DDNS via curl via cron to my router)
- `vps.sakujo.tld` (A record to my VPS on lowendspirit)
- `*.home.sakujo.tld`, `home.sakujo.tld` (they map to CNAME `gateway.home.sakujo.tld`)
- `mysql, ns01, nzbget, sonarr` (`.sakujo.tld`) (they map to CNAME `nas.home.sakujo.tld`)

So far so good and very simple. I run a home NAS based on Arch linux on an eeePc that can handle quite a lot of things at once apparently. One of them is now a bind installation. My intent is to override `home.sakujo.tld` and all its hosts but apparently I have to introduce quite a bit of redundancy to achieve those things.

### The need for a second zone

I want to achieve a set-up, naively speaking like this

```
gateway                 IN      A       192.168.0.1
nas                     IN      A       192.168.0.91
phone                   IN      A       192.168.0.41
user2.phone             IN      A       192.168.0.42
tab                     IN      A       192.168.0.43
htpc                    IN      A       192.168.0.51
tv                      IN      A       192.168.0.55
quad                    IN      A       192.168.0.101
red                     IN      A       192.168.0.111
```

I was hoping that a zone set up like this one would be all that is needed but sadly this turned out to be too naive and did not suffice. My hopes were that

1. `nas.home.sakujo.tld` (and `gateway.home.sakujo.tld`) would now resolve to `192.168.0.91` (and `192.168.0.1`) instead of the DDNS A record on namecheap's external DNS.
2. That way, if I used `mysql.sakujo.tld` or for instance `sonarr.sakujo.tld`, a DNS look up would first find the canonical name (CNAME) `nas.home.sakujo.tld` (as it of course does) and I was hoping that that canonical name had an A record to now `192.168.0.91` as defined in the zone file above. Sadly, in reality, `mysql` or `sonarr` resolve to `nas.home.sakujo.tld` (which is fine and wanted), **but that one still has the external A record as defined on namecheap** (the place that also defined the CNAME for `nas.home.sakujo.tld`).
3. So in essence I had to set up a second zone. I already had `home.sakujo.tld` and now I added `sakujo.tld`. That new zone now uses all the info that is already defined in namecheap's configuration I have externally. It goes like this:

   `mysql                   IN      CNAME   nas.home`

   `nzbget                  IN      CNAME   nas.home`

   `sonarr                  IN      CNAME   nas.home` *(I can't seem to get code to work here, apologies)*

But `mysql`, `nzbget`, `sonarr` already have the zone entries set on namecheap exactly this way. This seems redundant. Do I have to do this? Or can I make some vodoo entry somewhere on namecheap or in `home.sakujo.tld` and have it transfer/update/authority whatnot (I really don't understand things from here on out at all anymore, you probably noticed I tried to learn and understand everything that leads up to this point - from now on I am 5 years old).

### The @ and NS entries

First thing's quick: I don't know what to put into `sakujo.tld` @ A record and just have it point to `127.0.0.1`. Ideally I would just leave that entry out as I don't have anything that makes sense to map `sakujo.tld` to.

Next on, I am told / need to add these lines into the zones to make them "good"

```
$TTL 30
; home.sakujo.tld
@       IN      SOA     ns01.home.sakujo.tld. postmaster.home.sakujo.tld. (
                                        2015041917 ; Serial
                                        28800      ; Refresh
                                        1800       ; Retry
                                        604800     ; Expire - 1 week
                                        86400 )    ; Minimum
                        IN      NS      ns01
                        IN      NS      ns02
ns01                    IN      A       192.168.0.91
ns02                    IN      A       192.168.0.91
@                       IN      A       192.168.0.1
```

I know what the TTL is, the comment is probably irrelevant. I am sure I can look up the things in the brackets and I already know the Serial setting. My questions on this one are of more practical nature. Do I need all those entries?

- *both* NS entries and both A records referring them?
- The @ A record?
- The @ SOA entry? (I understand this is a very likely yes - heck I ask because chances are this is related to the first paragraph)

I also tried to replace the A record for @ with a CNAME entry to no avail. It would not resolve.

Either way, I read a lot that I should have two name servers. I guess it makes sense to set up another external DNS on a VPS? Is that trivial/would be identical to how I set up the first one? I guess there is a relation between the two ns01 entries and the appearance of ns01 in the SOA entry as well.

### Are there best practices I am missing?

Are domains even supposed to be set up that way? I currently use two distinct kinds of entries

- Unique FQDNs for physical/virtual hosts like `nas.home.sakujo.tld` for my NAS or `tv.home.sakujo.tld` for the tv (home being the location, a subnet) - so that is why for instance `vps.sakujo.tld` is not under home.
- Aliases that are semantically labeled. Like `mysql.sakujo.tld`. This will be my main MySQL server - I currently only use a single db in a MariaDB installation. Or `sonarr.sakujo.tld` - so that should map to whichever physical machine hosts my Sonarr installation. The advantage of this is that in a year I might use another machine for the MySQL database so the references in my configuration and data should be agnostic of the physical/virtual host .

Maybe there are things I don't see? Even if it is things like "It's more common to name your router `portal/router` instead of `gateway`".
For posterity, I pasted my complete `/etc/named.conf` and zone files. Now that I mention that I don't really know if I need the allow-update and notify settings but that part of the documentation I am able to follow myself (I just thought I'd mention this in case there are questions about why I have them in, I simply don't know)

named.conf

- [named.conf](http://hastebin.com/ejudacihel.avrasm)
- [zone config](http://hastebin.com/zaxebunuze.avrasm)

Now that I think about things it would be best to have the following nameservers set up

1. `ns01.sakujo.tld` pointing to `nas.home.sakujo.tld`
2. `ns02.sakujo.tld` pointing to the namecheap DNS

Can I use CNAMEs here? Do I have to set up `ns0#.home.sakujo.tld` as well? If so can I use CNAMEs there?

### Edit

Somebody in #bind on freenode wondered why I was using a separate subdomain for my home network to begin with. He advised me to use views instead.

Is it not arbitrary whether I put the hosts on my local network into their own subdomain? After all they are in their own subnet, too and semantically speaking it seems to make sense.

I read up a bit on views, but his advise does not seem to apply to me on a first quick and naive glance. I mean I don't intend to expose my local DNS to the internet so there is no point in having separate zone configuration for different clients. I want all the zone configuration to apply to all clients that use the DNS.

Maybe he was suggesting to use views on namecheap's DNS instead? Would that even work? Also, how would namecheap tell whether I make the DNS request from my home network or an external network to begin with? After all mapping my hosts on `home.sakujo.tld` to `192.168.0.0/24` would not help all that much when I am not in my local subnet.